# Cannot find config/cucumber.yml file

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Just to give a bit of background to my current problem: I have created a ruby project in Apanta studio 3 and created the usual folder structure: Project -- features -step_definitions-support.

I have created and run the .feature  file to give me cucumber code stubs:

```
Given(/^I am on Home Page "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I have created and coded the .rb file and put that in step definition folder. However--when I run the .feature file--it is not picking up the .rb in the step definitions folder.

I have tried to solve this by changing the cucumber.yml file, but for some reason I cannot seem to find this config/cucumber.yml file anywhere.  Does cucumber create this file in another folder somewhere?

Been trying to sort out this problem for awhile, and this seem to be the best solution to get my automation back up and running.

Comment: config/cucumber.yml should be in your project base folder. If its not something went wrong in cucumber setup

Comment: thanks for the swift reply.Here is my project path:C:\Workspace\EMT - should be in EMT project folder right? Know this should be basic stuff but been trying find this file for ages now

Comment: Yes then it should be in C:\Workspace\EMT\config\cucumber.yml if it is not as I said then there was something wrong with your setup. and maybe you should try and rebuild.

Comment: Hi, so uninstalled then reinstalled ruby 1.9.3, devkit, rails and cucumber gem.Edited .yml file. Executed feature file again an got same stubs again and no execution of step definitions.Any other sugestions?lines that were edited in .yml below: default: -r features <%= std_opts %> --tags ~@jruby --dotcucumber  features/.cucumber wip:-r features  --wip <%= wip_opts %> features

Comment: @user2568256 I am not that familiar with many of the options you are using. The -r features seems odd though. What I'd suggest is a) edit your question and add your entire cucumber.yml so others may help. b) try running tests with only the default cucumber.yml then add options until you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The cucumber.yml file is some thing that you create and not there by default, at least not on my installation i created one my self. Also your step definition may not be found because there is not an EXACT match. 'I love cheese' and 'I love  cheese' are NOT the same. The best thing to do in this case is to run cucumber on your feature file and use the suggested Given/When/Then header with your own code pasted in the body. The next time you run cucumber that step should now be defined.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can check is the syntax of the step in the feature file. May be its not picking the correct regular expression string. If you are using the default setup and you have the step definitions under the calabash_steps.rb or any .rb file in the same directory as calabash_steps.rb, there is no other setting needed in the config/cucumber.yml file.